# Bootstrap Sidebar last link not show in mobo view

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I create Bootstrap sidebar which is successfully working on both mobo and desktop view. But in Mobo view last tab/link is not showable or scrollable. Show in image after reverse of array i have one more link which is not scrollable.

[image]

Comment: please provided some of your html.

Comment: did you try `overflow:auto;`?Also, please add your html and css code of the sidebar.After that, it will be easy for us to help.